# Save pdf file from hyperlink list to folder

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, copy

I have a range in excel lets say A1:A50, and every cells contain hyperlink. I sort the range and get the only cells that needed..

Is there any ways using VBA, to save files in the hyperlink from the sorted cells to other folder?

The source link is from computer, not from internet URL.

thanks in advance.

Ciao

Below is the code
, I got this type of error when run it

Run time error '1004':
Sorry, we couldn't find (file name).pdf. Is it possible it was moved, renamed, or deleted?

```
Sub download ()

Dim linkfile As hyperlink
Dim wb as workbook
Dim savelocation As string

savelocation = "C:\(folder name)"

For Each linkfile In Thisworkbook.Sheets("sheet name").Hyperlinks
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(linkfile.address)
wb.Saveas savelocation & linkfile.Parent & ".pdf"
wb.Close True
Set wb = nothing
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Do the link cells target an internet URL or a folder Path? Anyhow, the hyperlink itself does not help. It can be used only to extract the URL or path...

Comment: It is on the another path, not from internet URL